# How do I setup an apt mirror that only gets security updates?

Tags: apt-mirror

I maintain a few dozen servers all running Lucid. Setting up a local mirror is probably a good idea anyway, but I also have a unique need.

The (ec2 instance) servers are all configured to get security updates *only*. That's how I want it. The problem is that when I create a new server/ec2 instance and download packages, those packages are completely current and out-of-sync with the rest of the cluster. I can use Chef to pin explicit package versions, but then minor updates will make whatever we pin unavailable.

**So what I'd like to do is this...** I want an apt mirror that mirrors the Lucid repository, but *only* gets security updates, not regular ones. Then by pointing all my servers to that mirror, I can keep everything running the same version, but also avoid unnecessary updates.

Setting up a mirror itself with apt-mirror seems simple enough, but what I'm missing is how to make sure the mirror only does security. How do I setup an apt mirror that only gets and propagates security updates? I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: [Rightscale](http://www.rightscale.com/) provides an Ubuntu mirror within ec2. Which is nice because bandwidth between EC2 instances is free. Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` to only contain: `deb http://ec2-us-east-mirror.rightscale.com/ubuntu lucid-security  main restricted multiverse universe`

Comment: Thanks, Andrewsomething. Although the issue is less bandwidth and more filtering of updates.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you set up your mirror, in your sources list `/etc/apt/mirror.list` only include the security archives

```
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu lucid-security
```